# How to disable a click event handler for particular time?

Tags: javascript, onclick

Only JavaScript, No jquery.

Code goes like:

```
window.onload = addListeners;
function addListeners(){
    for(var  i = 0 ; i < document.getElementsByClassName('arrow').length; i++){
    if(window.addEventListener){
        document.getElementsByClassName('arrow') [i].addEventListener( 'click', func , false);

    }else{
        document.getElementById('arrow') [i].attachEvent('onclick' , func);
    }
}
}


function func(){
//Takes exactly 5 seconds to execute
}
```

Now, I want to disable the 'click' for 5 seconds when the function 'func()' is running. And, then after the 'func()'  is completely executed, the click should again be enabled automatically.

How to do this only using JavaScript?

Comment: is there something asynchronous in `func`?

Comment: Yes!  func is asynchronous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To elaborate my comments on [Curts answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896864/how-to-disable-a-click-event-handler-for-particular-time/16896916#16896916):

When declaring the function func you can do two things:

```
function func() {
    if ( !func.isRunning ) {
        func.isRunning = true;
        /* logic goes here */
        func.isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Or you can make a closure and store isRunning inside it:

```
var func = (function() {
    var isRunning = false;
    return function() {
        if ( !isRunning ) {
            isRunning = true;
            /* logic goes here */
            isRunning = false;
        }
    };
})();
```

The second example can makes a private variable only accessible inside the closure.

---

Its mostly about a design pattern some developers doesn't like to store variables directly on functions like in example one. The only difference is that if someone chooses to set `func.isRunning = true` the function cannot run again and therefore not reset itself.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than disable the click event, check a variable to see if its currently running.

```
var funcRunning = false;
function func(){
  if (funcRunning) return;
  funcRunning = true;

  //Function logic here

  funcRunning = false;
  return //whatever  
}
```

This way your not guessing the function will take 5 seconds to run, the function will simply not execute its logic until its completed its current run.

**EDIT:** As [@NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896864/how-to-disable-a-click-event-handler-for-particular-time#comment24382508_16896916) has suggested, a better method would be to store the boolean variable on the function itself to prevent global pollution:

```
function func(){
  if (func.IsRunning) return;
  func.IsRunning = true;

  //Function logic here

  func.IsRunning = false;
  return //whatever  
}
```

Comment: Or you could store the boolean on the function itself to prevent global pollution.

Comment: @NULL Declaring the variable inside the function will declare each time the function is executed though, so you won't be able to share the variable value across multiple calls of the function. Unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: it is not inside the function.

Comment: @Curt `func.isRunning = true`.

Comment: He probably means the property assignment. But should it then return anything as it is supposed to be an object? Like: `var f = new func() ; `

Comment: @Curt `this` will refer to the DOM Node. And that way you will only prevent the same node from running `func` multiply times in less then five secs.

Comment: Javascript has only one execution thread. So, a function can't be called while it is still executing. So, both variants are not correct.

Comment: To clarify. It was just a suggestion not nesesary something you would think it smart/beautiful. Some people prefer to make a closure and return another to `var func = (function(){...})()`. If the functions name way blabla i would save it on `blabla` (`blabla.myVar`) AND: I like to use isSomething camelCase when dealing with booleans. But maybe my OCD is just kicking me...

Comment: @NULL I ain't getting this.. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @NavneetSaini Just posted an elaboration here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16897484/887539

Answer (score 1):

If your function is asynchronous (it sends ajax request, as far as I understood), you'd better create a "success" callback for that request and handle funcRunning flag there.

Here is an example:

```
var funcRunning = false;
function func() {
  if (funcRunning) {
    return;
  }
  funcRunning = true;
  var xmlhttp = new XmlHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open('GET', '/xhr/test.html', true);
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
       if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
         // do something.
         funcRunning = false;
       }
    }
  };
}
```

P.S. Current example is not the most correct in creating XmlHttpRequest instance (not crossbrowser). It is shown only as an example.